# Find and fill the missing time spot in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, missing-data

we are working on a pandas data frame which looks like below. Here the time column is in the increment of 15 minutes and there are some missing time entries. We want to fill the missing time entries with the corresponding date and populate all the corresponding field with zero's This is how the data frame looks like.

```
df=
date.y        timeslot_1  ProductId PlantId region  UserId  Gender  AgeGroup    Weights
6/07/2018   1:15:00         1002    8577       6      Mab   2           S       1432.6
6/07/2018   1:15:00         1002    8577       6      Mac   2           M       1629.3
6/07/2018   1:15:00         1001    8647       6      Maa   2           P       5299.6
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1001    7636       C      Mab   1           T       1626.4
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1002    8577       6      Maa   1           T       1476.1
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1002    8577       6      Mab   2           S       1432.6
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1002    8577       6      Mac   2           M       1629.3
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1001    8647       6      Maa   2           P       5299.6
6/07/2018   2:00:00         1001    8647       6      Maa   2           P       4731.6
6/07/2018   2:15:00         1001    7636       C      Mab   1           T       1638.6
6/07/2018   2:15:00         1002    8808       C      Maa   2           M       2465.3
6/07/2018   2:30:00         1002    7491       4      Mab   1           N       5419.8
6/07/2018   2:45:00         1002    7491       4      Mab   1           N       5419.8
6/07/2018   3:15:00         1001    8362       6      Maa   2           X       2227.6
6/07/2018   3:15:00         1002    8714       C      Maa   2           P       1820.6
6/07/2018   3:15:00         1001    8668       5      Mab   2           S       2048.4
6/07/2018   4:00:00         1002    8714       C      Maa   2           P       1820.6
```

We thought of creating another base file which would contain all the 15 minute incremented time with the corresponding date and then join the base file with the original data frame. However some how it doesn't seem to be working. The join just puts all the spots from the base file at the end of the every date. This is how the joined data frame looks like.

```
date.y        timeslot_1    ProductId    PlantId    region    UserId    Gender    AgeGroup    Weights
6/7/2018         1:15:00        1002        8577    6           Mab         2       S        1432.6
6/7/2018         1:15:00        1002        8577    6           Mac         2       M        1629.3
6/7/2018         1:15:00        1001        8647    6           Maa         2       P        5299.6
6/7/2018         1:45:00        1001        7636    C           Mab         1       T        1626.4
6/7/2018         1:45:00        1002        8577    6           Maa         1       T        1476.1
6/7/2018         1:45:00        1002        8577    6           Mab         2       S        1432.6
6/7/2018         1:45:00        1002        8577    6           Mac         2       M        1629.3
6/7/2018         1:45:00        1001        8647    6           Maa         2       P        5299.6
6/7/2018         2:00:00        1001        8647    6           Maa         2       P        4731.6
6/7/2018         2:15:00        1001        7636    C           Mab         1       T        1638.6
6/7/2018         2:15:00        1002        8808    C           Maa         2       M        2465.3
6/7/2018         2:30:00        1002        7491    4           Mab         1       N        5419.8
6/7/2018         2:45:00        1002        7491    4           Mab         1       N        5419.8
6/7/2018         3:15:00        1001        8362    6           Maa         2       X        2227.6
6/7/2018         3:15:00        1002        8714    C           Maa         2       P        1820.6
6/7/2018         3:15:00        1001        8668    5           Mab         2       S        2048.4
6/7/2018         4:00:00        1002        8714    C           Maa         2       P        1820.6
6/7/2018         1:15:00                            
6/7/2018         1:30:00                            
6/7/2018         1:45:00                            
6/7/2018         2:00:00                            
6/7/2018         2:15:00                            
6/7/2018         2:30:00                            
6/7/2018         2:45:00                            
6/7/2018         3:00:00                            
6/7/2018         3:15:00                            
6/7/2018         3:30:00                            
6/7/2018         3:45:00
```

Below is the code

```
date1='06/03/2018'
date2='06/10/2018'
d=pd.date_range(start=date1+ ' 02:00:00', end=date2+' 02:00:00', freq='15min')
columns=['date']
all_spots=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
all_spots=all_spots.assign(date=d)
all_spots=all_spots.astype(str)
all_spots = pd.DataFrame(all_spots.date.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['date.y','timeslot_1'])
d=pd.merge(df,all_spots,how='outer', on=['date.y','timeslot_1'])
```

This is how the result would look like.

```
date.y        timeslot_1  ProductId PlantId region  UserId  Gender  AgeGroup    Weights
6/07/2018   1:15:00         1002    8577       6      Mab   2           S       1432.6
6/07/2018   1:15:00         1002    8577       6      Mac   2           M       1629.3
6/07/2018   1:15:00         1001    8647       6      Maa   2           P       5299.6
6/07/2018   1:30:00           0      0         0       0    0           0         0
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1001    7636       C      Mab   1           T       1626.4
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1002    8577       6      Maa   1           T       1476.1
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1002    8577       6      Mab   2           S       1432.6
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1002    8577       6      Mac   2           M       1629.3
6/07/2018   1:45:00         1001    8647       6      Maa   2           P       5299.6
6/07/2018   2:00:00         1001    8647       6      Maa   2           P       4731.6
6/07/2018   2:15:00         1001    7636       C      Mab   1           T       1638.6
6/07/2018   2:15:00         1002    8808       C      Maa   2           M       2465.3
6/07/2018   2:30:00         1002    7491       4      Mab   1           N       5419.8
6/07/2018   2:45:00         1002    7491       4      Mab   1           N       5419.8
6/07/2018   3:00:00           0      0         0       0    0           0         0
6/07/2018   3:15:00         1001    8362       6      Maa   2           X       2227.6
6/07/2018   3:15:00         1002    8714       C      Maa   2           P       1820.6
6/07/2018   3:15:00         1001    8668       5      Mab   2           S       2048.4
6/07/2018   3:30:00           0      0         0       0    0           0         0
6/07/2018   3:45:00           0      0         0       0    0           0         0
6/07/2018   4:00:00         1002    8714       C      Maa   2           P       1820.6
```

P.S. One thing to note is it is just a snippet of data. We have data for one month. So we need to take care of the date and the time is in 24 hour format.

We were hoping if some one can please help to get this resolved.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create another dataframe to join with your dataframe.

```
# Change "1:15", "4:00" to "0:00, 23:59" for your actual data.
hr_range = pd.date_range("1:15", "4:00", freq="15min").strftime('%H:%M:%S')

# Remove 0 to match your format
hr_range = hr_range.str.lstrip('0')

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['timeslot_1'] = hr_range
df2['date.y'] = pd.to_datetime('2018-06-07')
```

Then convert `date.y` to `datetime` and `set_index` both dataframe with `['date.y', 'timeslot_1']`.

```
df['date.y'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date.y'])

df.set_index(['date.y', 'timeslot_1'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['date.y', 'timeslot_1'], inplace=True)
```

And `join` them together with `how='outer'`

```
df.join(df2, how='outer').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Alternative solution without using `.set_index`

```
(df.merge(df2, on=['date.y', 'timeslot_1'], how='outer')
   .sort_values(['date.y', 'timeslot_1'])
   .fillna(0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. One thing to note is that the `date.y` is not a single date. It is also a range of date. We created the range using `pd.date_range(start=date1+ ' 02:00:00', end=date2+' 02:00:00', freq='15min')`. however we had to convert that to string in order to split them in dates and time in seperate column. Also, The date and time in the original data frame are date time format. Do you recommend to convert them into string as you are creating the `hr_range` in string format

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam You can use `pd.date_rage(start_date, end_date)` instead of 
 a single date. Also before splitting your `datetime` into date and time, you can use your `pd.date_range` and `set_index` then `join` them together. I have to convert it to `string` make it joinable with your example dataframe.